# Get the latitude and longitude of point after being moved

Tags: python, math, maps, astronomy

I have some point A with latitude and longitude (x, y) and i want to know the latitude and longitude of a new point (B) which is the point A after moving it 75km to the right with an angle theta (compared with the equator).
Please anyone has an idea i'll appreciate it.

A(x, y)  ------------75km--------->  B(x', y')

```py
from math import sqrt,atan,pi
import folium
import pyproj


geod = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')

width = 75000. # m
height = 75000. # m
rect_diag = sqrt( width**2 + height**2 )

center_lon = -0.5493
center_lat = 35.7108

azimuth1 = atan(width/height)
azimuth2 = atan(-width/height)
azimuth3 = atan(width/height)+pi # first point + 180 degrees
azimuth4 = atan(-width/height)+pi # second point + 180 degrees

pt1_lon, pt1_lat, _ = geod.fwd(center_lon, center_lat, azimuth1*180/pi, rect_diag)
pt2_lon, pt2_lat, _ = geod.fwd(center_lon, center_lat, azimuth2*180/pi, rect_diag)
pt3_lon, pt3_lat, _ = geod.fwd(center_lon, center_lat, azimuth3*180/pi, rect_diag)
pt4_lon, pt4_lat, _ = geod.fwd(center_lon, center_lat, azimuth4*180/pi, rect_diag)

wkt_point = 'POINT (%.6f %.6f)' % (center_lon, center_lat)
wkt_poly = 'POLYGON (( %.6f %.6f, %.6f %.6f, %.6f %.6f, %.6f %.6f, %.6f %.6f ))' % (pt1_lon, pt1_lat, pt2_lon, pt2_lat, pt3_lon, pt3_lat, pt4_lon, pt4_lat, pt1_lon, pt1_lat)

print(wkt_point)
print(wkt_poly)

m = folium.Map(location = (35.697070, -0.630799), tiles="Stamen Terrain", zoom_start=6)
folium.Marker(
    [35.697070, -0.630799], popup="<i>Mt. Hood Meadows</i>", tooltip='oran'
).add_to(m)
folium.Rectangle([(pt1_lat, pt1_lon), (pt3_lat, pt3_lon)], weight=2, color="red").add_to(m)

m.save('sat.html')
```

Comment: Please try to show your own research first. Have you searched internet for the relevant solution? If not, try reading [this great article on global distances](https://www.auraq.com/distance-calculations-using-latitudes-and-longitudes). If you cannot implement the formulae in python language, what problems are you facing? Did you get an error -> include it in your post, do you not know a particular syntax, search stackoverflow, google, documentation, tutorial sites. If the problem still persists, post all your work: your code, the formulae you are using, any errors or outputs here.

Comment: I tried to solve it without the angle but still don't get the exact results i want

Comment: This is my first post in stack I don't know how to share my code here and they're not allowing me to post photos so.. I'm sorry 

Comment: Copy your code by pressing `CTRL` + `A` , then `CTRL` + `C`. Then edit your question. And add a new line to the end of your question. Add another new line by pressing `Return` or `Enter`. Then add triple backticks. Add another new line. Paste your code by pressing `CTRL` + `V`. Then, add another new line. Then, add another triple backticks. Then, add another new line.